# Solution for finding polar coordinates given arc length

Tags: circles, polar-coordinates, arc-length

What is the general theorem and/or proof that allows one to deduce the *X* and *Y* values of a point that lies on a circle if given the arc length from another point on the same circle?

I made a quick picture in Paint to demonstrate my question better.

[image]

Given coordinates of the **blue point**, and an **arc length** (in red), how can one determine the coordinates of the **yellow point**?

Comment: Without a central angle or the radius, this is insufficient information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $(x_b,y_b)$, the coordinates of the blue point, the $y_b$ value is the radius of the circle.

$y_b=r$

So now find the angle (in radians)

$arc length=r\theta_b$

$\theta_b=(arc length)/y_b$

$\pi/2-\theta_b=\theta_y$

Then use basic trig equations (cos and sin) with the radius $r=y_b$ to find the coordinates of the yellow point.